# how is 1st code working to get 21 while when same value is assigned to **b** the post increment operator doesn't work?

Tags: c, operators, post-increment, pre-increment

when running the below code the output is **21**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{int a=10,b=10;

printf("%d",a+(a++));

}
```

whereas running below code gives output **20**

```
int main()
{int a=10,b=10;

printf("%d",b+(a++));

}
```

how is 1st code working to get 21 while when same value is assigned to **b** the post increment operator doesn't work?? (10+10++) in case of a it will work as 10+10=20 then ads 1 and shows the value where as in case of b it will only do 10+10=20 and shows the value. why? is it showing this?

Comment: In C++ (not sure about C) your first code has *undefined behaviour*, the output could have been anything. It is forbidden to modify a variable and reference it in the same expression. That is a big simplification of the rules, see the duplicate for more details. Because your second code uses two separate variables the behaviour is well-defined.

Comment: Your title suggests that you think the output of `20` from your second program is incorrect. That is not true, maybe you need to revise how the post-increment operator works, as well as learning about undefined behaviour.

Comment: `printf("%d",a+(a++));` Please don't write code like that - it will cause you a world of grief.

Comment: The code `b+(a++)` is well-defined and makes sense.  We take `b` and add `a`'s old value, and as a side effect we also increment `a`.  But the similar-looking expression `a+(a++)` is, in C anyway, *un*defined and makes no sense.  Since we're incrementing `a` as a side effect in the process of evaluating the expression, there's an ambiguity: does the `a` on the left-hand-side of the `+` operator (that is, where `b` used to be) use the old or the new value of `a`?  There's no rule to tell us.  (And left-to-right evaluation is *not* guaranteed.)